# Eliminar varios registros con checkbox en rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Porque llega null?

controller

```
def multiple_destroy
  Article.where(id: params[:articles]).destroy_all

  redirect_to articles_path
end
```

route

```
delete 'articles/multiple_destroy'
```

view

```
<% @articles.each do |article|%>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<%= article.id %>" name="articles[]" id="article_<%= article.id %>">
            <label for="article_<%= article.id %>"></label>
          </th>
          <td><%=article.code%></td>
          <td><%=article.name%></td>
          <td><a href="/articles/<%=article.id%>" class="btn-flat waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons right">keyboard_arrow_right</i>view</a></td>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
      <div class="fixed-action-btn vertical">
       <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
         <i class="large material-icons">menu</i>
       </a>
       <ul>
         <li class="btn-floating red"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></li>
         <li class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><a rel="nofollow" data-method="get" href="<%= articles_multiple_destroy_path %>"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></li>
         <li class="btn-floating orange"><a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal_search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
         <li class="btn-floating green"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">file_upload</i></a></li>
         <li class="btn-floating blue"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons">cloud_download</i></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Matías, bienvenido. Te recomiendo que pases por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que vayas conociendo el sitio. Sobre tu pregunta, ¿podrías editar y aclarar que es lo que llega null y brindar mas datos sobre el problema?

Comment: Hola marcos, gracias! lo que llega null es el arreglo articles, cuando llega el momento de eliminarlos me dice que no se puede eliminar porque la clase esta null, espero que me entiendan(no soy bueno explicando...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El arreglo ´articles´ llega `nil` debido a que no estás enviando nada al dar clic en el enlace `delete`, simplemente estás reenviando a tu acción, pero sin parámetros.

Para lograr el comportamiento que buscas (i.e. borrar los checkboxes a través de un enlace), yo haría lo siguiente:

**app/views/articles/index.html.erb**

```
<table id="articles">
  <% @articles.each do |article|%>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<%= article.id %>" name="articles[]" id="article_<%= article.id %>">
        <label for="article_<%= article.id %>"></label>
      </th>
      <td><%=article.code%></td>
      <td><%=article.name%></td>
      <td><a href="/articles/<%=article.id%>" class="btn-flat waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons right">keyboard_arrow_right</i>view</a></td>
    </tr>
  <%end%>
</table>

<div class="fixed-action-btn vertical">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red"><i class="large material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul>
    <li class="btn-floating red"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></li>
    <li class="btn-floating yellow darken-1">
      <%= link_to tests_multiple_destroy_path, id: "delete" do %>
        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
      <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="btn-floating orange"><a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal_search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
    <li class="btn-floating green"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">file_upload</i></a></li>
    <li class="btn-floating blue"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons">cloud_download</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var ids = [];

      $('#posts :checked').each(function() {
        ids.push($(this).val());
      });

      window.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?articles=" + ids;
    });
  });
</script>
```

- Agregué el *tag* `table` (que me imagino omitiste por error) y le puse un `id` (i.e. `articles`) para poder hacer referencia a él con *JavaScript*/*jQuery*.
- Utilicé el *helper* `link_to` para generar el enlace `delete` y le puse un `id` (i.e. `delete`), para poder hacer referencia a él con *JavaScript*/*jQuery*.
- Generé un `script` el cual, al dar clic en el enlace con `id="delete"`, lee los valores de los *checkboxes* seleccionados (a través de la tabla con `id="articles"`) y los agrega como *querystring* a la ruta especificada en el link (e.g. `"?articles=1,2,3"`).

**config/routes.rb**

```
get 'articles/multiple_destroy'
```

- Cambié `delete` por `get` para facilitar el envío de parámetros.

**app/controllers/articles_controller.rb**

```
def multiple_destroy
  Article.where(id: params[:articles].split(",")).destroy_all

  redirect_to articles_path
end
```

- Agregué `.split(",")` pues el valor `params[:articles]` es una cadena de texto con los `id` que quieres borrar separados por una coma; `split(",")` generará un arreglo con los `id` (necesitas un arreglo para que `where` seleccione todos los valores).

Comment: undefined method `join' for "2,3":String?

Comment: @MatiasCarpintini. Ohh, un error de mi parte; debes utilizar `split` en lugar de `join`. Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!